# MasterDetailPage not loading Details

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

Trying to get a basic MasterDetailPage running to learn Xamarin. When I build and run the code, it loads tha master ok, but not the detail pages. I tried stepping through the code and I noticed a bunch of X's on some of the variable properties, but I really don't know how to fix this outside of starting over again.

[Here's a link to my GitHub repository.](https://github.com/blksheep93/blksheep93.github.io/tree/FirstBranch) Any help is appreciated.